# How to add googlesheet checkbox to the google sheet toolbar

Tags: google-sheets, checkbox, toolbar, google-sheets-api

I am a starter in coding in Googlesheets (google scripts). I want to create a google script to add a checkbox to the toolbar of the google sheet. Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: What do you mean by the toolbar? [This?](https://imgur.com/JEYx9zm.png)

Comment: yes @RafaGuillermo

Comment: In which case this isn't possible, unfortunately.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo what about adding checkbox in the bar below the tool bar (the bar with Bold, Underline, Italics, etc). Can it be possible?

Comment: There's no way of modifying that menu at all either, you're limited to creating a new menu item, but checkboxes are a no-go.

Answer (score 1):

### You cannot add a checkbox into the toolbar but you can create an HTML custom [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs) with checkboxes

- For this, use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- Follow the [guide for custom sidebar creation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars)
- Create an html file with checkboxes
- Use [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to communicate between serverside and client side of the code

**Sample:**

Code,gs

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
  .createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
  .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
  .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
  .showSidebar(html);
}

function setValue(checked) {
  var value;
  if(checked == true){
    value = "number 1";
  } else{
    value = "number 2";
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  cell.setValue("You clicked the checkbox: " + value);
};
```

index.html

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" >Click me <br>
<input type="checkbox" > Or me <br>
<input type="button" value="set value" onclick="evaluateInput()"> 
</div>

<script>
  function evaluateInput() {
    var checkedFirst = document.getElementById("check").checked;
    google.script.run
      .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
      .setValue(checkedFirst);
  };

  function onFailure(error) {
    console.log(error.message);    
  };
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]